# "Water under the fridge"

Tags: idioms

I was watching *Dumb and Dumber*, and Lloyd said "Water under the fridge" instead of "Water under the bridge" ( That's all water under the fridge now, Har. Think of the bright side. You're finally getting to meet her, and you never had to change all those poopie diapers )

I believe the expression is 'bridge,' not fridge, is it a misquote common expression for comedies to sound stupid ?

Comment: Whatever doesn't kill you, simply makes you *stranger*. - Joker

Comment: *is it a misquote common expression for comedies to sound stupid?*  This so-called "comedy" is *Dumb and Dumber*.  Wasn't that a clue?

Comment: Without knowing more of the context it's hard to say, but often such "misquotes" of common idioms make sense when considered in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The idiomatic phrase is "water under the bridge," which means

> "Something that ​happened in the past and cannot now be ​changed."

From: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/water-under-the-bridge

You are also correct that it is common to misquote common expressions in comedies to sound stupid for comedic effect.

You might also want to Google "malapropisms" to find other amusing examples, such as these:

"He had to use a fire distinguisher.

Dad says the monster is just a pigment of my imagination.

Isn't that an expensive pendulum round that man's neck?

Good punctuation means not to be late.

He's a wolf in cheap clothing.

Michelangelo painted the Sixteenth Chapel.

My sister has extra-century perception.

"Don't" is a contraption."

All of these are from http://www.fun-with-words.com/malapropisms.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case it is meant to be amusing. Mis-speaking idioms is often silly because we expect one thing, and get something other. You can think of this as a very simple example of *absurdism*.

To answer your question about this phrase, no; it has been done before:
[trailer park boys](http://trailerpark.wikia.com/wiki/Rickyisms)

Comment: Just to note:  your "trailer park boys" had their first episode in 2001.  Dumb and Dumber is from 1994.

Comment: @Jim In your attempt to correct me(and presumably the source of the down-vote, you failed to realize this line is from "Dumb and Dumber To", which came out in 2014. :rolls eyes:

Comment: if I were to down vote you I would tell you about it.  (I guess I shouldn't have taken OP at his word on the source of the quote, oh well.)   I only down vote when an answer is wrong to the point that someone believing the answer would come away with fundamentally wrong information.

Comment: @Jim I think blaming the OP is pretty absurd here; if you're interested in correcting someone, I believe the onus falls on you to verify what you're saying. I do however apologize for suspecting you down-voted; it seemed logical that based on your comment, you might have done the deed.

Comment: This is two rich!